# View document content in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, document

I have a gridview. It contains all the details of document stored in a system. There is a button "Click" in the gridview.
.. my problem here is that, when user clicks the button 'Click', the user should be able to view the document contents. Is there any methods to do that without using Ms word GOM or such?

The documents are all located in hard drive.

Worst case scenario if, it has to be done via Word, can u please teach me how to do it?
User should be able to Read/view access.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Can you use iFrame's to hold the file?